# Held him in small worth

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could you possibly explain what is the meaning of the phrase

> Held him in small worth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "***hold in small worth***" means someone being considered of very little value/worth(or no value at all).

Therefore, in your sentence:

> Held him in small worth

There are two being people being spoken out. The first person(*he/she/you*) considers the other person(*him*) to be of very little value, or, in other words, of not much use.

The closest one-word synonym of the phrase "***hold in small worth***" can be: ***Disparage***

Per [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disparage):

> ***dis·par·age** *verb*
>
> *to describe (someone or something) as unimportant, weak, bad, etc*.

And, the Google definition of disparage:

> ***disparage***
>
> *verb: disparage; 3rd person present: disparages; past tense: disparaged; past participle: disparaged; gerund or present participle:
>   disparaging*
>
> **regard or represent as being of little worth.**

This example is similar to a sentence where your phrase "hold in small worth" could be used:

> *"He never missed an opportunity to disparage his competitors"*